# Routing in locomotive using ejs

Tags: node.js, routes, locomotivecms, locomotivejs

I'm trying out node and some frameworks for node atm, specifically locomotive.  However, i seem to be stuck on routing using locomotive.  A couple questions i can't find the answer to, so here goes:

1. why does the locomotive out-of-box install use index.html.ejs as a
   filename?  Why not just index.ejs?  What's the benefit?
2. i'm trying to add a route to a view: searchName.html.ejs which i
   added in the views folder.  To achieve this i made a toolController
   like this:

   ```
   var locomotive = require('locomotive').Controller,
   toolController = new Controller();

   toolController.searchName = function() {
       this.render();
   }

   module.exports = toolController;
   ```

   I also added a route in routes.js like so:

   ```
   this.match('searchName', 'tool#searchName');
   ```

   However, that doesn't work (and yet it's what the documentation says ought to     work).    The result is a 404 error.  So how do i make that route work?
3. Suppose i want to make a route to eg, anExample.html?  How do i go
   about that?  I notice that in the out-of-the-box app from
   locomotive, you cannot enter localhost:3000/index.html .  Nor even
   localhost:3000/index  This seems highly impractical to me, as there
   are plenty of users who'll add the specific page they want to go to.
   So how can i make that work?

PS: I went through all questions regarding this on stackoverflow and searched the web, but i still can't figure this out.`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The benefit is that this naming scheme allows you to specify several different formats for a single route. So you could have `search_name.html.ejs` and `search_name.xml.ejs`, then respond with either view depending on what your client is expecting.
2. There are a couple issues with the example code you posted. You should be seeing a more descriptive error than a `404`, so I'm not sure what's happening there, but here are the fixes to your code that work in my environment.

   In the controller:

   ```
   //tool_controller.js
   var locomotive = require('locomotive');
   var toolController = new locomotive.Controller();

   toolController.searchName = function() {
     this.render();
   };

   module.exports = toolController;
   ```

   In routes.js:

   ```
   //routes.js
   module.exports = function routes()
   {
     this.match('searchName', 'tool#searchName');
   }
   ```

   Then, you'll need to change the view to this: `views/tool/search_name.html.ejs`. It's not clear from the documentation, but locomotive automatically lowercases and underscores actions that are camel-cased, like searchName.

   Now start the app and browse to `http://localhost:3000/searchName`
3. If you just want to serve a static html file, the easiest way is to just drop it in the `public` folder. This folder is specifically for serving up static content like client-side js, css, etc. And it works just fine for serving static HTML as well.